# What is a convenient way to upgrade dependencies across multiple npm projects?

Tags: reactjs, npm, open-source

For open-source library authors, especially React-related, it is common for them to have written and published multiple React components. However, when React releases a new version (e.g v16), it is a hassle to upgrade each of those components to the latest React version.

What's a convenient way to upgrade the React dependencies in all those packages, with stability in mind? I don't want to be manually going into each project and running `npm update` as that will take very long. I considered writing a script to do it for me, but I'm wondering if there is any tool out there they can do the same or even better, and upgrade packages in all my projects at once?

This question is not really specific to React, it can apply to Angular, Vue, etc, or other commonly used npm library as well.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to update dependencies:

```
npm update
```

It will update only on based ranges in package.json, eg. from 1.0.0 to 1.9.0, but not to 2.0.0. See [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning). It's not good idea to setup automatic major version upgrade in package.json, so usually `npm update` will ignore major releases.

If you want to upgrade dependencies **major versions**, it's more trickier. There is high possibility that there will be breaking changes in libs, and you would need to **upgrade your code as well**.

What can help you with **update to latest** versions is this library **[npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)**.

```
 npm install -g npm-check-updates
 ncu // Shows new dependencies
 ncu -u // Will do upgrade in package.json
```

This library will search for latest packages and even will do update.

Specifically for `React` there is CLI which may be used, if you don't need custom webpack build. [React-create-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) will create application with hidden dependencies like React, ReactDOM, Jest, Webpack, .. and when you want to upgrade then it's as simple as updating one dependency for whole React&Webpack stack.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```

If you are building similar applications (but cannot use ReactCLI), you can build your own webpack configuration which might be reused in all your application and it will cover build process. This might hide build dependencies like `Webpack`, `React`, `Router`, etc.

Update: **Is possible to upgrade multiple projects quickly and seamlessly? eg. with simple script.**

It's probably very complicated or even impossible. You would need to have exactly same dependencies in all projects... as you might have some incompatible versions of different libs. Probably best way would be to create common libraries stack like `react-cli` has and then use this stack as single dependency. But still you would need to upgrade and test each project separately after upgrade of "stack" dependency - also usually you would also need to upgrade codebase because of API changes. Making update script may be quite complex and probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry but I'm asking a different question here. 

I know how to update the dependencies for one project. My problem here is that I want to update the dependencies in multiple packages at once.

Comment: I've updated response - probably not worth to build such upgrade script, as it's so complex, and APIs of libraries changes quite often...
Maybe someone else has experience with this, but probably it's not common in JS world. And yes, if you want to speed up install, or update you may try `yarn` as it's few times faster than `npm4`, and a little faster than `npm5`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on gitlab, github, self-hosted gitlab and other related source control you can check my answer [What is the best way to authomatically update project dependecnies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261208/what-is-the-best-way-to-authomatically-update-project-dependecnies/62261860#62261860)

Long story short you can use **Renovate** which is a great tool to update your dependencies across different package manager like maven, npm, gradle, pip and other package managers. It can update dependencies for multiple project at once and also it has other benefits. actually  it automatically create merge request with those update whenever new update are available for those dependencies. **although it can be used outside CI/CD but if you have CI/CD with creating those merge request it can run your pipeline and make sure everything is OK after that update.**